# Acceder array externo dentro de Lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

Tengo este código:

```
int data[] = {
  1,
  2,
  4
};

server.on("/path", HTTP_GET, [&data] (*request) {
    data[0] = 100;

    setData(data[0], data[1], data[2]);
});


void setData(int a, int b, int c) {
     // ...
     // a = 1, b = 2, c = 4
}
```

Donde necesito acceder al array y modificar un item, pero los valores del array real no se cambian.

He intentado usar `[data]` en la captura y tampoco me sale.

Comment: Pon un ejemplo de lo que quieres lograr. Eso es C o C#?

Comment: @Japv eso no es C ni C#. Es C++.

Comment: @Mateo igual está mal, tiene que arreglar las etiquetas

Comment: Si se ejecuta la función lambda, se modificará el primer elemento de tu array. Los otros dos no se modificarán ya que la función `setData` recibe los elementos por valor, no por referencia. Si `data[0]` no ha cambiado de valor, es que la función lambda no ha sido ejecutada dentro de `server.on`.

Answer (score 0):

El lambda está bien. Es necesario que pases la variable por referencia si quieres modificarla, de lo contrario el compilador te dará error ya que `data` sería una variable de solo lectura.

```
//                            ↓
server.on("/path", HTTP_GET, [&data] (*request) {
    data[0] = 100;

    setData(data[0], data[1], data[2]);
});
```

Por la declaración y el comentario en la función intuyo que quieres modificar las variables que se pasan como parámetro:

```
void setData(int a, int b, int c) {
     // ...
     // a = 1, b = 2, c = 4
}
```

El problema es que así solo estás reasignando los parámetros.

Para que la asignación tenga efecto en las variables originales necesitas que la función reciba referencias:

```
void setData(int &a, int &b, int &c)
```